# FireBase adding data to tables manually

Tags: ios, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 tables that I want to populate in my iOS application looks like the following:

[image: my tables are here]

What I want to do is find a way to manually populate the last two tables myself, so that when a user comes in and registers (and inputs the ipconfigcode) I will be able to look up the two tables I manually entered. Is this possible? If so could you point me in the right direction or explain how to do so?

That would be a ton of help!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Firebase does not have a concept of tables - that's an SQL thing. Firebase has parent and child nodes which consist of key: values pairs; very similar to a Dictionary. Are you asking how to read and write data to Firebase? Do you have an existing Firebase structure and perhaps some code you've tried? If so, post it (as TEXT please, no images) and we'll take a look. In the meantime, please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about the structure of the question, I will try to do better next time. Thanks for the feedback. Also, I haven't really done anything yet besides a user login and password authentication. However, What I'm trying to figure out is if I can write to nodes in the console provided by firebase? Or do I have to make an interface in my iOS application to be able to write to nodes?

Comment: You can definitely write, edit and remove nodes using the Firebase Console. In the rules section, you can also create and test security rules as well.

Comment: Oh thats good news! And I assume I will be able to use the data that I write as a lookup table? For example, If I give a user a unique key will I be able to look for that key in one of the nodes and use the information I wrote specifically for that certain key? -- thanks a bunch for the quick response!!

Comment: Again, no such thing as a table in Firebase. And yes, to your question but it sounds like you are going about whatever it is the wrong way; while you can use the console to write and manipulate data, it's really more for testing (in general) than anything else so you should be creating an app that does those things.

Comment: I'm trying to build an app for iOT devices so I need some way to store the users ip address and what kind of devices they are using. So that when I load the profile, I will be able to us the Ip address in the REST calls I make.Would you think making an admin side to this application would be better? -- Sorry for all the questions but you are helping me alot and I thank you for that

Comment: One option would be when the app starts on the device, capture that info and when the user registers in Firebase, store it in a /users node. However, IP addresses are often dynamic in nature (via DHCP on a router for example) so that's probably not a good way to target a device; but it depends on your use case. I would strongly suggest going through the [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup), write some code and a basic test app that reads and writes some data to Firebase so you can see how it works, then post a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: awesome!! thanks this actually helped me understand all this alot more clearly!